# Find Lexicographical greatest string by increasing vowel characters

Tags: java, string

I was solving a problem on a contest, but could not clear all the test cases.

Here is the problem:

You are given a string S and an integer Q. You are allowed to perform at most Q operations on the string. In one operation, you can change any vowel to it's next character (e.g., 'a'->'b', 'e'->'f', 'i'->'j', 'o'->'p', 'u'->'b'). Generate the lexicographically greatest string by performing at most Q operations on string S.

```
E.g.
S=abcde
Q=3
output=bbcdf
```

Explanation: We have string "abcde" and we are allowed to perform at max 3 operations, we can form lexicographically greatest string by applying the operation on first and last character of string by changing the string to "bbcdf",which is lexicographically greatest

My code:

```
 String in=br.readLine();
 int Q=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

 char [] inarray=in.toCharArray();

 int start=0;
 int l=inarray.length;
 while(start<l)
 {
    if(Q==0)
    break;
 if(inarray[start]=='a'||inarray[start]=='e'||inarray[start]=='i'||inarray[start]=='o')
 {
     inarray[start]=(char)((int)inarray[start]+1);
   Q--;    
 }

// System.out.println(inarray[start]);
 start++;


 }

 String out = new String(inarray);
 System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: You should add a language tag.

Comment: okay , done that

Comment: why `output=bbcdf`  and not  `output=dbcde` ?

Comment: we can change only vowels

Comment: @munnusingh is it an online website this question came from? Can I have a link?

Comment: Warning - the link goes to a site which breaks all possible privacy considerations.

Comment: You should scan the string and start with the first occurring vowel, then the next etc.

Comment: I have done that only.

Comment: Bro 'u' should change to 'v'. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Question iteself was wrong.It said change 'u' to 'b'

Answer (score 0):

This is a Hiring challenge problem by one of the Indian IT Company Hot Star, That's why they asked for Phone and Email @Wow.

PS: I don't have 50 Reputation that's why i made a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaLearn.StringEx;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RePrintVowels {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NumberFormatException, IOException {

          BufferedReader scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("enter limitcount");
            int nextInt = Integer.valueOf(scanner.readLine());

            for (int nn=0 ; nn <nextInt ; nn++){

                String nextLine22 = scanner.readLine();
            //  scanner.nextLine();
            //  System.out.println("enter LImit");
                int nextInt2 =Integer.valueOf(scanner.readLine());
                message(nextLine22,nextInt2);
                //  scanner.nextLine();
            //  System.out.println("enter string");
                String nextLine1 =scanner.readLine();
                int nextInt3 =Integer.valueOf(scanner.readLine());
                message(nextLine1,nextInt3);
            //  scanner.close();

            }
            scanner.close();
    }
    public static void message(String StringData,int Limit ){

        /*String texta=StringData;*/

        StringBuilder texta = new StringBuilder(StringData);
        int charArray = texta.length();

        int ij =Limit;
        int it=1;
        if(ij >0){


        for(int i1=0;it<=ij&&i1<charArray ;i1++){
            if(texta.charAt(i1) =='a'
                ||texta.charAt(i1) =='e'
                ||texta.charAt(i1) =='i'
                ||texta.charAt(i1) =='o'
                ||texta.charAt(i1) =='u')
            {
                System.out.println("vowles  :::"+texta.charAt(i1));
                int codePointAt = Character.codePointAt(texta, i1);
                System.out.println("codePOint :::"+codePointAt);
                char c =(char)(codePointAt+1);
                System.out.println("next vowel value ::"+c);
                texta.replace(i1, i1+1, String.valueOf(c));
            //  texta=texta.replace(texta.charAt(i1), (char)(codePointAt+1));
                it++;
            }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("string  :::"+texta);    
    }




}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forget to add one vowel `u` condition. Try this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read on [answer] and edit your answer to provide more value.

Comment: If I change 'u' to 'b' then string would be smaller I guess